# How to implement an algorithm to separate lambda calculus terms using Böhm's theorem?

Tags: lambda-calculus

> Theorem 1 (Böhm, 1968) Let $Λ$ be the set of closed normal forms,
> and let $S1$ and $S2$ be arbitrary λ-terms. For any non η-equivalent
> terms $T1, T2 ∈ Λ$ there exists a λ-term $∆$ such that the application
> of $∆$ to $T1$ evaluates to $S1$ and the application of $∆$ to $T2$
> evaluates to $S2$. [source](http://www.di.unito.it/%7Edezani/papers/dgp.pdf)

Is there an algorithm to find λ-term $∆$ for a given $T1, T2$?

A [similar question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17928/is-there-a-systematic-method-for-constructing-lambda-calculus-terms-that-can-dis) was asked and answered. I read the whole paper referenced in the answer. But there is no mention of the real algorithm and whether the procedure is decidable. It just tells us that it is enough to use 3 types of λ-terms to discriminate $T1, T2$:

[image]

The hard part is to choose which λ-terms to use and what is the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Gérard Huet, [“An Analysis of Böhm’s Theorem”](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00074664) (1993) explains his [implementation in ML](https://gitlab.inria.fr/huet/cct/-/blob/master/bohm.ml), and Ben Lynn has another well-explained [implementation in Haskell](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/lambda/bohm.html) that you can try out on the web page.